# Multi boot USB flash drive

Tags: linux, windows, usb, multi-boot

Please how do I make a multi boot USB flash drive? to boot live Linux distros or Windows ISO images?
let's say I have Kali Linux, Gentoo, Ubuntu, and other Linux distros, Windows 7 32 bit and Windows 7 64bit ISO files
Thank you in Advance

Comment: Do you mean similar to this http://www.linuxliveusb.com/en/home ?

Comment: You may also find this helpful http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/